# created on the first call CNN : Value Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network, resnet

First code

```
class ResBlock(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, filters, downsample):
        super().__init__()
        if downsample:
            self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters, 3, 2, padding='same')
            self.shortcut = keras.Sequential([
                layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, 2),
                layers.BatchNormalization()
            ])
        else:
            self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters, 3, 1, padding='same')
            self.shortcut = keras.Sequential()

        self.conv2 = layers.Conv2D(filters, 3, 1, padding='same')
```

second code

```
class ResNet(keras.Model):
def __init__(self, resblock, repeat, outputs=1000):
    super().__init__()
    self.layer0 = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Conv2D(64, 7, 2, padding='same'),
        layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'),
        layers.BatchNormalization(),
        layers.ReLU()
    ], name='layer0')
```

last code i build code for `Resnet34`

so, after i ran the code finished and i ran this code

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

callbacks = [
  # Write TensorBoard logs to `./logs` directory
  keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./log/{}'.format(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")), write_images=True),
]
resnet34.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])
resnet34.fit(train_generator, epochs=30, steps_per_epoch=195,
          validation_data=validation_generator,
          validation_steps=3, callbacks=callbacks)
```

the code problem. and the value error is

```
ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables created on the first call. Make sure the tf.Variable is only created once or created outside tf.function. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables for more information.


Call arguments received:
  • input=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 56, 56, 64), dtype=float32)
```

focus the line `tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables created on the first call`, and i don't know how to troubleshoot this problem, i hope you can help me.

Comment: code for resnet34

Comment: class ResNet34(ResNet):
    def __init__(self, outputs=1000):
        super().__init__(ResBlock, [3, 4, 6, 3], outputs)